# custom toolbar not visible in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am using custom toolbar. but it is not showing proper result as required. in my design view it shows fine. but when i run the app search bar which i added is not showing. follow the screen shots for more details.

This is my required out put. and in my design view it shows same.
[image]

header_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/header_home1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header_home_iv_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_home_ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/header_ib_menu"
            style="@style/ibHeader"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/dimen_50"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu" />

        <!--android:background="@drawable/bg_search_header"-->


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/header_ib_my_cart"
            style="@style/ibHeader"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_5"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cart_white" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/header_ib_notification"
            style="@style/ibHeader"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_notification_white" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_home1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_home_iv_header_bg2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_home_ll_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_search_header"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/header_ib_search"
                style="@style/ibHeader"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white" />

            <com.lessohome.customview.CustomFontTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:shadowColor="@color/colorFontDarkGray"
                android:shadowDx="1"
                android:shadowDy="1"
                android:shadowRadius="2"
                android:text="@string/search_for_products"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
                app:fontText="@string/Muli_Bold" />

            <!--android:shadowColor="@color/colorFontDarkGray"
            android:shadowDx="1"
            android:shadowDy="1"
            android:shadowRadius="2"-->

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/header_ib_qr_code_scan"
                style="@style/ibHeader"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_scan_white" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i run the app, it shows only this much part of toolbar. even in my fragment_home.xml ,in design view it shows same. search bar is not showing.

[image]

fragment_home.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/fragment_home_tb_toolbar"
        style="@style/toolbarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_4"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/fragment_home_header"
            layout="@layout/header_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue, I am not able to find what is wrong am i doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Height of toolbar and other relative layouts are same i.e.   android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

That's why there is only Header layout is visible not the search layout because header layout occupying the whole height of the toolbar and search layout is below the header layout.
Change the height of toolbar and you will get the desired result.

Comment: what to change?

Comment: change the Height of toolbar to twice of  android:attr/actionBarSize Default value for android:attr/actionBarSize = 56dp and its depend on the device resolution. So make toolbar height to 112dp.

Comment: i changed it as wrap content, now it is visible but now i am facing scrolling issue..my viewpager is not visible..

Comment: @arvid i changed layout as per my requirement now issue is, my toolbar is covering half view of the viewpager images..right now half images are visible i want to make full visibility..can you help

Comment: @chris Keep the viewpager below the toolbar. It will be very helpful if you can show the viewpager XML file. Without seeing the xml file I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout_below for the search view should be

```
android:layout_below="@id/header_home1"
```

instead of

```
android:layout_below="@+id/header_home1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give height of toolbar

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

instead of

`android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336515/google-analytics-not-refecting-in-fragment