# Google Analytics is not reflecting in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-analytics, abstract-class

I am using Google Analytics in my app. I have fragments in my app. I created on base fragment as an abstract class. and using it for remaining fragment. Can any one help me to solve this?

This is how I created my abstract class and extend it to fragment

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment{..}
```

In this base fragment, I added google analytics code, and I am able to track it in analytics.

Now I have another class created in this way.

```
public class FirstFragmemt extends BaseFragment {..}
```

In this fragment also I added analytics code, but it is not tracking or reflecting.

Can anyone tell what is the reason for that?

Comment: where is the code you are using in your Basefragment?

Comment: @ZeroOne the code is working fine in basefragment. i added google analytics code in on resume method.